# pop up windows for uploading success

Tags: php, ajax

I would wish to upload a documents, and upon success uploading, there is an ajax call back from the server regarding the successful upload, and at the front end I would pop up a windows telling user the upload has been succeeded, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Short answer: Yes there is. Have you written any code?

Answer (score 0):

[Session Upload Progress](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) describes how you can track the progress of an upload.